# Как заменить текст в тегах?

Tags: javascript, jquery

При выполнении функции js

```
    function foo(){ 
      var a;
      $('p.message').html('Привет!');
      a ='true';
      if(a=='true') {
        $('p.message').html('Пока!');
      }
    }
```

Появляется первое сообщение и остается, не меняется.
Как сделать, чтобы сначала появилось 'Привет', а затем 'Пока' ?

Comment: `$('p.message').html('Привет!').delay(1000).html('Пока!');` кажется так можно

Comment: Там немного кода выполняется между сообщениями, посмотрите код.

Comment: Надо, что бы условие было истинно. У вас сейчас `a=='true'` равно `false`.

Comment: Вот я исправил. Смысл не в том. Функция сначала выводит первое сообщение, выполняет код, затем выводит второе. А второе не выводится, а остается первое.

Comment: В вашем примере выводится как раз второе.

Comment: Должно выводится, но не выводится. Текст не заменяется в тегах.

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотели получить такой эффект?

```js
function foo(){
 $('p.message').html('Привет!');
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('p.message').html('Пока!');
  }, 1000)
 }
foo();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='message'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

В примере ниже примется во внимание только последняя строчка кода: `box.style.display = "block";` Это произойдет потому, что в начале выполняется основной поток (весь твой `js`), а когда полностью весь он выполниться, то тогда наступает очередь рендеринга - обновление картинки до состояния актуальной. В него входить вычисление `Style Calculation`, `Layout`, `Paint` еще входит `Request Animation Frame`, и он вроде первый идет по списку, но это другая история. Так вот в момент подготовки кадра уже учитываеться конечный результат, по этому в твоем примере в силу вступает `$('p.message').html('Пока!');`.

```js
function style() {
 box.style.display = "none";
 box.style.display = "block";
 box.style.display = "none";
 box.style.display = "block";
 box.style.display = "none";
 box.style.display = "block";
 box.style.display = "none";
 box.style.display = "block";
}

style();
```

Можно сделать с помощью `setTimeout`.

```js
let a = true;

function foo() {
  if (a) {
    $('p.message').html('Привет!');
    a = false;
    setTimeout(foo, 2000);
  } else {
    $('p.message').html('Пока!')
  }
}

foo();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="message"></p>
```

Если хотите лучше понять почему так происходит, то можете посмотреть [хорошее видео про Event Loop](https://youtu.be/j4_9BZezSUA).